# What is the best location to initialise the DynamoDB instance (Lambda + NodeJS)?

Tags: node.js, aws-lambda, aws-sdk

I have a lambda-layer with the code below:

```
class PersonModel {
    constructor(tableName, values) {
        // some implementation
    }

    async save() {
        // some implementation

        return docClient.put({
            TableName: this.tableName,
            Item: this.values
        }).promise();
    }
}
```

Inside my lambdas implementation I instantiate the PersonModel to implement a kind of CRUD. It's something like that:

```
exports.handler = async (request) => {
    const person = new PersonModel('profile', { name: 'John' });
    person.save().then(d => {
        return {
            statusCode: 200,
            body: 'Person saved!'
        }
    }).catch(err => {
        return {
            statusCode: 500,
            body: 'Something went wrong!'
        }
    });
};
```

My question:

Where is the best place to put the DocumentClient instance?

Here (at the js file level):

```
const docClient = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient();
class PersonModel {
    constructor(tableName, values) {
        // some implementation
    }
    // etc...
```

Or here (inside the object implementation - it will create one instance for each lambda call):

```
class PersonModel {
    constructor(tableName, values) {
        // some implementation
        this.docClient = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient();
    }
    // etc...
```

Or is it better in somewhere else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the DynamoDB [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Streams.Lambda.BestPracticesWithDynamoDB.html):

> - AWS service clients should be instantiated in the initialization code, not in the handler. This allows AWS Lambda to reuse existing connections, for the duration of the container's lifetime.
> - In general, you do not need to explicitly manage connections or implement connection pooling because AWS Lambda manages this for you.

Also note that some services like Amazon RDS have a [limit on the maximum number of open connections](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/CHAP_Limits.html), so that is something to keep in mind if you ever work with such a service. DynamoDB should not have any such limits.